# haproxy streaming - no dependency on proxy

Tags: haproxy

I have been testing with haproxy which does cookie based load balancing to our streaming servers, but lets say for example haproxy falls over (I know unlikely)
the streamer gets disconnected, is there a way of passing on the connection without it relying on haproxy, basically laving the streamer connected to the destination and cutting all ties with haproxy.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a programming Q&A. You stand a better chance of getting an answer on https://serverfault.com

Answer (score 0):

That is not possible by design.

HAProxy is a proxy (as the name suggests). As such, for each communication, you have two independent TCP-connections, one between the client and HAProxy and another between HAProxy and your backend server.

If HAProxy fails or you need to failover, the standing connections will have to be re-created. You can't pass over existing connections to another server since there is a lot of state attached to each connection that can't be transferred.

If you want to remove the loadbalancer from the equation after the initial connection initialization, you should look at Layer-3 loadbalancing solutions like LVS on Linux with [Direct Routing](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/VS-DRouting.html). Note that these solutions are much less flexible than HAProxy. There is no such thing as a free lunch after all :)